# The method decodeResource(Resources, int) in the type BitmapFactory is not applicable for the arguments (Resources, String) in Android

Tags: java, android, bitmap, drawable

Currently i have slider images, where each image is placed on single slide page with the "share" button on top of it. if clicked on share button current Page image should be shared via email and mms, to do this first i need to convert the images to bitmap from drawable. arg_object.getString("image")) is the url of image. i'm able to get for converting individual images but not for overall. please help me.

heres my code for it

```
Bitmap bbicon = { BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.cordova.getActivity().getResources
                    (),"R.drawable."+arg_object.getString("image"))};
```

but on decodeResource i'm getting error as `The method decodeResource(Resources, int) in the type BitmapFactory is not applicable for the arguments (Resources, String)`

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html. check the docs. should it not be `R.drawable.something` without `""`. param requires a int

Comment: to get the id you can use `drawableResourceId = this.getResources().getIdentifier("nameOfDrawable", "drawable", this.getPackageName());`

Answer (score 1):

I am no sure i understood right but:

- if in `arg_object.getString("image")` you have the resource name then there is not a direct way to load the bitmap, but you can still manage to get it dinamically.

  first resolve the resource identifier by the name like this:

  ```
  String name = arg_object.getString("image");
  String defType = "drawable"
  String defPackage = "com.android.yourpackage";
  int drawableId = getActivity().getResources().getIdentifier( name , defType, defPackage );
  ```

  now that you have the resource id you can easly create a bitmap with [one of the BitmapFactory methods](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeResource%28android.content.res.Resources,%20int%29):

  ```
  Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource( getActivity().getResources(), drawableId );
  ```
- if instead in `arg_object.getString("image")` you have the image uri, just use:

  ```
  Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile( arg_object.getString("image") );
  ```

Comment: i'm getting unable to attach, file not supported error @Mario Lenci

Comment: can you Log what's in  arg_object.getString("image") and add it to the question? I can't help you if i don't know what's in there.

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
int resourceID = getActivity().getResources().getIdentifier(arg_object.getString("image"), "drawable",getActivity().getPackageName());
Bitmap bbicon =  BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getActivity().getResources(),resourceID);
```

The second param is id which is an int value. But you have `"R.drawable."+arg_object.getString("image")` which makes it a String. I guess you get get the name with `arg_object.getString("image")` and you can get the resource id as above.

For more info

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html

```
public static Bitmap decodeResource (Resources res, int id)

Added in API level 1
Synonym for decodeResource(Resources, int, android.graphics.BitmapFactory.Options) will null Options.

Parameters
res The resources object containing the image data
id  The resource id of the image data
Returns
The decoded bitmap, or null if the image could not be decoded.
```

Comment: not able to share the image, i'm getting, unable to attach, file not supported error @Raghunandan

Comment: is that a url? what does this return `arg_object.getString("image")`. does this return the name of the drawable or is it a url as you mentioned?

Comment: yes this is url only, i'm able to get the name of the image. @Raghunandan

Comment: @DD can you post the `url` and what do you mean by share.

Answer (score 0):

If imageView is a ImageView which carry your image resource then,

BitmapDrawble bd = (BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable();

Bitmap bitmap = bd.getBitmap();